# How can I access the values in this NSDictionary in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to access the 'address' object (String) in a dictionary:

```
Chain.sharedInstance().getAddress("19b7ZG3KVXSmAJDX2WXzXhWejs5WS412EZ"){  dictionary, error in
            NSLog("%@", dictionary)
            let value = dictionary["address"] as? String //returns nil
        }
```

this is the data I receive:

> ```
> results =     (
>             {
>         address = 19b7ZG3KVXSmAJDX2WXzXhWejs5WS412EZ;
>         confirmed =             {
>             balance = 0;
>             received = 20000000;
>             sent = 20000000;
>         };
>         total =             {
>             balance = 0;
>             received = 20000000;
>             sent = 20000000;
>         };
>     }
> ); }
> ```

How do I access the values in this dictionary when I keep getting nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify, the data you are posting is not JSON, but rather looks like JSONP.  You aren't showing any code deserializing the the object, so I assume Chain.sharedInstance().getAddress is handling that aspect.  If this is an instance of the Bitcoin API, you might look at their documentation.  If it is their API, the documentation says the return is

> A dictionary with a single "results" key, whose value is a array
>   containing a single Address Object as a dictionary.

If that is the case if would be

```
if let resultsArray = dictionary["results"] as NSArray {
    if let dict = results[0] as NSDictionary {
        //dict["address"] should have your address
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if let dict = dictionary["results"] as NSDictionary
{
     let value = dict["address"] as NSString
}
```

or:

```
if let dict = dictionary["results"] as NSArray
{
    if let di = dict[0] as NSDictionary
    {
           let value = di["address"] as NSString
    }

}
```

Comment: For both i receive error '(NSObject,AnyObject)' does not have member named 'subscript'.

Comment: with optionals it just skips the entire loop, without them it shows that error in red.